# Redirect URI for browser based client

Tags: electron, identityserver4, openid-connect

There might be an obvious answer to the question but I just can't figure it out:

Currently, my setup is running locally (the IDS, the API and the Client(s)) and works like expected.
The client in my scenario is an Angular app running on the users desktop using Electron.NET. In the IdentityServer4 configuration I have configured the redirect URIs as following: `RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc" }`

My question now is how to setup the IDS correctly if the parts are not running locally on my PC but somewhere else. This would mean that the angular app runs on some device I am not aware of beforehand (meaning I don't know it's IP address). Thus I don't know the correct URI beforehand and as a result can't setup the **predefined** redirect URI required by IDS.

Answer (score 1):

Your angular app should be using an implicit grant client. implicit clients are used for client side web applications.  These applications are running in a users browser and hosted on your website. Due to the fact that its hosted on your website you should always know what the redirect uri should be and will be able to add it correctly in your identity sever.

Example:

> "http://yourawsomesite.com/signin-oidc"

Documentation on implicit flow can be found

- [Javascript client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html)
- [Implicit](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/)

If you dont know what the redirect uri will be then i think you have a different problem entirely.

Comment: Oh, looks like i was not specific enough. My angular app is actually running as a desktop client application inside Electron.NET and are therefore not hosted on my website. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: you can try localhost but that may only work if the Identity server is also running on your desktop. Implicit grant type was never meant to be used in a native environment.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try this. In case this does not work, what would be an appropriate way of accomplishing this?

Comment: thanks again, I will check this out. However, I am a bit confused as I really thought that implicit is the right flow. The sample from the oidc client i want to use uses the implicit flow aswell. I have fired up the sample and it worked fine with the implicit-flow (also running the angular app locally on my machine). You can find the implementation here: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: It may work i just have no experience of making a windows application using angular.   Not sure how you would use a hybrid client with a client based programming language.